# How do I add an alias for a naked domain with OpenShift?

Tags: ssh, openshift, openshift-client-tools

How can I make my naked domain to point to my Openshift application?

Can it be done in the Openshift online dashboard or it can only be configured through the `rhc` utility? However I am not sure which the steps to do it.

Comment: can you please explain it more what you looking for ....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a two-step process:

1. First, make sure that you have a DNS provider that offers support for naked `CNAMES`, then and add one or more `CNAME` entries that point to the URL that OpenShift provided for your application (APPNAME-NAMESPACE.rhcloud.com or similar).
2. Next, use the `rhc alias` command to let OpenShift know that you would like your application to be made available whenever a request is received via any of the `CNAME`s configured in your DNS.  *This step can also be completed on the Web via your [OpenShift app management dashboard](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications).*

For example, if you had an OpenShift application named `wordpress` that you wanted available at `wordup.com`, your `rhc alias` command might look like this:

```
rhc alias add wordpress wordup.com
```

I wrote up a post to help answer this question here: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/domain-names-and-ssl-in-the-openshift-web-console

Comment: I'm using Yahoo DNS hosting, I doubt they support it, unless you mean A Record to point to other domain or IP address?

Comment: I've posted updated notes here: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/domain-names-and-ssl-in-the-openshift-web-console

Answer (score 2):

The answer was simple,

1) Add the Openshift DNS as A Record target.

2) Then add alias to the Openshift app like example.com

With that when example.com is accessed it will go to the app hosted in Openshift.

Comment: how do I get Openshift DNS IP?

Comment: I added the IP i get by pinging the openshift app url, as the A Record target. And *.mydomain.com CNAME to the app hostname. myapp-namespace.rhcloud.com

Comment: @JabranSaeed did you add the Openshift DNS A record with your domain  with your Domain console

Comment: by Openshift DNS A record you mean the IP that I get when i ping my own openshift provided hostname?